# New partition table for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-installation

I had Linux installed on my laptop, I decided to install Windows 7. There were several linux partitions, I resized one and formatted it to NTFS, couple left untouched, I decided to merge them during installation into one. When I was installing Windows, I was unable to merge partitions.
The question is: how do I create new patition table, i.e. delete all old partitions and create new.

Comment: you mean, all partitions have linux only. Now you want to remove those and install windows 7. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a new one.
Open up **Start** -> right-click on **Computer**.
Choose "**Manage**".

When the `Computer Management` window pops up, double-click on **Storage**.
Then choose **Disk Management (local)**.

Here, you can remove all the Linux partitions (implying you use Windows's boot loader, and not GRUB anymore), and *expand* the NTFS partition(s) of yours.

Comment: I am unable to expand partitions. This option is inactive. Any ideas?

Comment: After removing the partitions? (Notice: Remove them entirely. It may happen that an extended partition remains, taking up all the available space. Remove that _too_.)

Answer (score 0):

With the help **FDISK**, you can remove & create a partition.

1. **FDISK** is MS-DOS Command.
2. Using this, first remove your unnecessary partition and create a single partition.
3. Using your **Windows 7** CD, install the **OS**.
4. After installation, Type **Disk Management** on **Run** (you will see **"Create & format hard disk partitions"**) then you can create more partitions as you required.

Refer this URL related to **[FDISK](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/255867)**

Answer (score 0):

Boot to the Windows setup disk.  Choose "Drive options (advanced)" when you get to the "Where do you want to install Windows?" dialog.  You can then delete the existing partitions, then either select the empty disk (in which case Windows will partition automatically) or explicitly create partitions as desired.

Answer (score 0):

If Windows 7 is already installed, you ought to be able to use the built-in disk management snap in to delete, add, and resize partitions. If not, you can use a tool like [GParted Live](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/resizing-adding-partitions-with-gparted-live/).